# Pmap over tidyeval function

Tags: r, dictionary, tidyverse, purrr, tidyeval

I have created the following function to count the number of terminations in a company by variable in the dataframe.

```
 emp_term_var <- function(data, colName, year = "2015") {
  colName <- enquo(colName) 
  term_test <- data %>%
    filter(year(DateofTermination) == year) %>%
    group_by(UQ(colName)) %>%
    count(UQ(colName)) %>%
    clean_names()
  return(term_test)
}
```

I plug in my arguments and decide I want to see the number of terminations by department. The second argument of the function is the name of a column in the dataframe. I could do this for position and managername as well.

```
emp_term_var(df, Department, year = "2015")
```

This returns:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
# Groups:   department [5]
  department               n
  <chr>                <int>
1 Admin Offices            1
2 IT/IS                    4
3 Production              15
4 Sales                    1
5 Software Engineering     2
```

I have data from 2010 to 2018 and would like to map over this function for every year using a vector for the year argument:

```
years <- c("2010" ,"2011" ,"2012" ,"2013" ,"2014", "2015" ,"2016","2017" ,"2018")
```

I try to map the function with pmap with the following code:

```
pmap(list(df, Department, years), emp_term_var)
```

But I get the following message:

```
Error in is.data.frame(.l) : object 'Department' not found
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Maybe this works: `map(years, ~ emp_term_var(df, Department, year = .x))`.

Comment: This worked great and now map clicked for me. Thank you! @TimTeaFan

Comment: You haven't included any data, so we don't know what `Department` is

Comment: @camille Department is the name of the column in the data, df. The column Department is of type character.

Comment: If you make a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/5325862) we might be able to run your code